# model get join tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to cakephp. I have table customers with this

```
 id, product_id, created, modified
```

and my product table has this

```
id, label, cost
```

I want to select all the records from customer table which has the product_id in product table (join on id may be)?

How can I do that

Comment: What do you mean by *"which has the product_id in product table"*? Every customer that has a corresponding product in the products table? That *should* be all, unless your data is corrupt... Confused.

Comment: We need to know you have your models and relationships setup correctly, and from which controller you are trying to access these from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a hasMany association in your model for the table you would like to query, then do your `$this->Model->find('all'...)` query and make sure in your options you specify `recursive=>1` so that it will get your associated data.  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany